# what extension for uploading drawings from gimp to facebook

Tags: 13.10, gimp, facebook

Today I upgraded to Ubuntu 13.10 from 13.04. It looks good. I didn't test Gimp Image Editor on the 13.04 version but I just tested the 13.10 version with a painting with Gimp and when I tried to upload the file to facebook it tells me that this is an invalid image.

I have an older laptop with ubuntu 12.04 and have the same Gimp installed in it. With the 12.04 version I have plenty of extensions for filing the images that I do on gimp and can upload them to facebook. I noticed that the 13.10 version has only a few extensions for saving a file from gimp.

Which extension should I use to save a file that facebook will accept in this 13.10 version?

Answer (score 2):

When you go to the "Save as" the formats available are kinds that keeps all of your work in progress inside GIMP, such as layers, transparency and such settings.

If you want to share your work on Facebook you have to export your image as a bitmap-type of file. Go to "Files" > "Export" and you will have plenty of formats to choose from that will allow you to upload it to Facebook and other services, such as .png and .jpeg.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this was different before, but you need to *export* your picture, not save it.

Open `File -> Export`

[image]

and from there you can select from a range of file formats including `.png` and `.jpg` to save your file as:

[image]